# Unable to generate code using build_runner for dart_frog project

Tags: dart, dart-pub, build-runner, dart-frog

I have a dart_frog server code running on a Google Cloud - Compute Engine instance. I have used stormberry as the ORM for my postgres DB which generates code using `build_runner`.

Now, the issue is that, when I run `dart run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs`, it returns the following error:

```
Building package executable... (44:35.0s)
Built build_runner:build_runner.
Invoked Dart programs must have a 'main' function defined:
https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#a-basic-dart-program
```

---

The thing is this was running absolutely fine a couple of days ago and I have been able to generate code previously. I just made a minor tweak in the business logic and pushed it to the server. I have been encountering this issue since then.

```
build_runner: ^2.3.3

Dart SDK version: 2.19.6 (stable) (Unknown timestamp) on "linux_x64"
```

---

The same code works fine in my personal laptop though. I tried cloning the project again as well as deleting the `.dart_tool` folder and running `dart pub get` and `dart pub cache repair` but the issue still persists.